# How to load images intelligently using CSS/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, image-preloader, preloading

I have a thumbs `div` (i'm only showing four thumbs for the sake of brevity):

> ```
> <div id="thumbs">
> <img src="graphics/thumbs/01.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb objects" id="project01" />
> <img src="graphics/thumbs/08.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb web" id="project08" />
> <img src="graphics/thumbs/14.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb freehand" id="project14"/>
> <img src="graphics/thumbs/04.jpg" width="190" height="190" class="thumb freehand objects" id="project04" /></div>
> ```

and an empty `div` called 'content':

> ```
> <div id="content"></div>
> ```

and a hidden `div` called 'preload':

> ```
> <div id="preload">
> <span id="project01_content"><img src="graphics/010.jpg" /></span>
> <span id="project02_content"><img src="graphics/022.jpg" /><img src="graphics/021.jpg" /><img src="graphics/023.jpg" /><img src="graphics/020.jpg" /></span>
> <span id="project03_content"><img src="graphics/030.jpg" width="450" height="600" /><img src="graphics/031.jpg" width="450" height="600" /></span>
> <span id="project04_content"><img src="graphics/040.jpg" width="775" height="600" /><img src="graphics/041.jpg" width="775" height="600" /></span></div>
> ```

which I thought would be a nice way to preload all the images in the gallery. My jQuery uses the ID of the clicked thumbnail to `clone()` the images from the corresponding `span` and drop them into `content` using the `html()` method. The problem is, the gallery has a hundred images, not four, and already if I click one of the lower thumbnails the `content div` sits empty until ALL the other images before it are loaded.

What's the best way around this? My first thought is maybe there's a way to queue or de-queue image loading? Dim the thumbs till their content is loaded? Do away with the `preload` altogether in favor of a better way? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `IMG` tags in the HTML, the browser will load all of them regardless if they are hidden or not. Different browsers do this in different ways, f.ex IE has less "slots" than chrome/ff.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the problem. How to get around it?

Comment: I think you need to involve the side of the server....have it send you the pictures you need....or maybe just swap src attributes?

Comment: FYI, I used the load() event to animate opacity of each thumb whose first corresponding image has loaded. It produces such a pretty cascading effect while loading that you don't ebven mind the time it takes for images to stream in.